# Can't load workbook to openpyxl

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I have file path problem when loading an Excel file using *`openpyxl`*.

```
>>>openpyxl.__version__ 
'2.5.12'
>>>jupyter.__version__
'5.7.4'

import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

>>>os.getcwd()
'/Users/barbara/Documents/17_BMO'

path = "Users/barbara/Documents/17_BMO/Region.xlsx"

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

Instead of loading the workbook, I instead receive the error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/barbara/Documents/17_BMO/Region.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I have two same excel files saved in Desktop and Documents.  I firstly pointed workbook's path to Desktop, somehow, I can't load excel in Python, then I changed the path to Documents, it didn't work neither.  Later on, I changed back to Desktop as my path, it worked.  Don't why.

Comment: I thought maybe it could be having the wb open while you run your code, but that works fine. I notice the your path didn't have a drive name in it in your post. Did you by chance update it to 'C:/Users/barara...' etc?